# Can not override methods of DateFnsUtils class in Mui v5 to change weekday label of DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, overriding

I am using Material Ui V5 Datepicker. I got an issue when I custom DateFnsUtils to change displaying weekday label. I can not override the `getWeekdays()` method of DateFnsUtils.
[datepicker-weekday-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFf6M.png)

If I use Material Ui v4, it will be run very exactly what I want.

here my code

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {DatePicker, LocalizationProvider} from "@mui/lab";
import { enAU } from 'date-fns/locale';
import DateFnsUtils from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import "./App.css";
import {TextField} from "@mui/material";

class CustomDateFns extends DateFnsUtils {
  constructor() {
    super({locale: enAU});
  }

  getWeekdays() {
    return ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
  }
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([null, null]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={CustomDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          label="Basic example"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Also want to localize weekdays (and months when opening the calendar).